# My installer program is crashing due to exception: 0xE0434352

Tags: visual-studio, installation, installshield

I used Visual studio installshield to create an installation program and sent it to the server. When I tried to run the application on the server I get the following Microsoft windows message:

{” Myapplication has stopped working”
A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available”}

When I click the Debug button.
I get the following exception:
[There is an unhandled win32 exception occurred in Myapplication.exe [6620]]

When I click debug using the selected debugger which is New instance of Visual Studio 2008
Microsoft visual studio threw the following exception:
[Unhandled exception at 0x76effd1e in Myapplication.exe: 0xE0434352: 0xe0434352]

Can someone help, please? I have no clue what any of this exception and error means.

Comment: `0xE0434352` is the code for a low-level CLR exception. Psychically debugging this one will be very difficult, if not completely impossible.

Comment: Are you using any custom actions ?

Comment: You should clarify the question. Your subject says "installer program stop working" but your post seems to be about the installed application crashing.

Comment: @PhilDW the application is crashing because of exception. I have included the exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the resource's to solving this exception here @ stackoverflow, as suggested by @kynrek or rephrase by @kynrek,

By adding a handler for “AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException as described here @

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception”

@kynrek should have credit for this answer.

```
     Public Class Form1
        Dim currentDomain As AppDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
        AddHandler currentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf MyHandler
        Try

        Catch ex As Exception
            ErrMsgTextBox1.Text = (ex.Message)
        End Try

    Private Sub MyHandler(sender As Object, args As UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)
         Dim e As Exception = DirectCast(args.ExceptionObject, Exception)
         ErrMsgTextBox1.Text = (e.Message)
    End Sub 'MyUnhandledExceptionEventHandler
End Class
```